# Who emits this vocalization near the end of Ad Astra?

Tags: dialogue, ending, ad-astra

Near the end of Ad Astra, Roy unclips the tether connecting him to his father, Clifford. This is followed by a shot of Clifford drifting away. After a few seconds of silence, a short scream is heard. Who screamed? Was it a cry of anguish from Roy? Was Clifford suddenly overcome by regret? Was Roy followed to Neptune by one of those feisty baboons?

Comment: Might be hard to answer without an actual copy of the screenplay...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roy face is visible just at the end of the scream and for less than a second you can see he is the one who is screaming.